# Spring Data Elasticsearch removing plus sign (+) in @Id field

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am developing a Spring Boot application with elasticsearch and I am using spring data elasticsearch. I have `id` field annotated with `@Id`. And for the id field I am inserting a value that contains some symbols including (+) plus sign. Something like this `10245365#1245+78965`. When ever I get the data I see the (+) is replaced with a space. And the id is now `10245365#1245 78965`. So is there any fix to allow even symbols for @Id? So anybody can help me? I really appreciate that.

Comment: which setup do you use? reactive or non-reactive? I'll have a look into this as Spring Data Elasticsearch should be able to do the encoding and decoding.

Comment: Which version of Spring Data Elasticsearch do you use? I just tried this with the current 4.2.0-M4 version, both reactive and non-reactive code, and there is nothing that is needed in the application code to encode or decode the id. You just can use the String `"10245365#1245+78965"` as id property or argument to the different functions within Spring Data Elasticsearch. How do you store and retrieve the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that since the ID is part of the URL of the document (i.e. `PUT index/_doc/id`), ES considers that everything is [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), and hence, when decoded the `+` sign is replaced by a space.

What you need to do is to URL-encode your ID before sending it to ES so that the `+` sign gets encoded into `%2B` and then properly decoded again as `+`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and also for your time.

Comment: actually I would expect Spring Data Elasticsearch to do the encoding and decoding, I'll have a look into this

Comment: @P.J.Meisch it's certainly possible to do it in the converters

Comment: no task of converters. I just tried this, there is nothing needed to be done, see my comment to the question. The question is, how does the OP store and retrieve the data